# Restore a 140GB - 292 Million entrie MySQL-Database faster?

Tags: mysql, innodb, restore

i need help. I have an old innodb Server and my storage limit reached.
I dont use files per table entries because in old times there were no ability at this time. My ibdata grown up fast and there is no ability to optimize them expect files per table. It is a productive database consists about 292 Million mails.

I dump my sql on a separate disk on production server

```
mysqldump --databases --single-transaction --quick -uroot -p databasename | gzip > backup.gz
```

and i restore with that

```
gunzip < backup.gz | mysql -u root -p databasename
```

I need more than 7h to restore the gzip dump on a 8(16th) Core i9 9900, 64GB DDR4 and NVME drive...it takes to long

Is it better to use an other backup method oder better dump directives or dont use gzip, dont know.

I made some optimizations on the restore test server:

```
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 8000
innodb_io_capacity = 80000
innodb_thread_concurrency= 0
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_buffer_pool_size=45G
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=128M
#table_open_cache       = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
```

Comment: Might be better to copy the raw database files directly if you don’t want to actually change anything (and you’re restoring to the same version)

Comment: I'm missing a step or two...  Did you take a dump onto a different server?  And you are now loading the dump into a server with a bigger disk?  Meanwhile, you can't fit 100 billion rows in 140 billion bytes.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake there are just 292.939.529 Mails....I make the dump on a separate disk on production server...I just want to flush the overhead of ca. 30 GB so i need to optimize it...I have to redump it but bevor i have to check it for dump erros....look, if i delete ibdate to recreate and the dump is not consistant i will crash my company

Comment: [innodb_log_file_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) could be increased to 0.5G. With NVMe, [innodb_flush_neighbors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_neighbors) should be 0. [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) could be set to 0 during load (only) though on NVMe. I'm still at a loss explaining why this is taking 7hrs. What MySQL version? What filesystem?

Comment: at production server 5.5 and 5.7 on new server...It is compressed to 26GB...maybe the unzipping? I/O top shows 100MB/s maximum is 200MB/s file system ext4 on restore server. I use a raid 0 with two 1tb NVME SSD to speed up more but no sucess.... an other way is to change the mysql path on the production server and copy all files to a new empty larger disk, what do you think?

Comment: 1h and 50GB thats good but one table have 90% of data, maybe this is the slower...looking forward to the rest

Comment: Additional information FROM new 5.7 srver. Post on pastebin.com share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 4 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: I need more than 7h to restore the gzip dump on a 8(16th) Core i9 9900, 64GB DDR4 and NVME drive. There is one table with 280 millionen of data, the processes stuck there, it needs many time